# Are measurements of battery voltage enough to test its state of health?

Tags: batteries, resistors, multimeter

What I mean is that I might have 3.5 battery voltage, and I rarely use it.

Note:

If I measure the voltage it shows 3.5, but is not the internal resistance changed decreasing the current?

If that is correct, then measuring the voltage is not enough for diagnosing the issue. The power that the battery can supply must be measured.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please clarify your question? What’s the end goal? Measure state of health, state of charge, ESR, voltage or something else?

Comment: Hi @winny
Measure state of health

Comment: Please edit your question to state so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right – from the open-circuit voltage, you cannot infer the internal resistance, nor the remaining battery capacity.

> The power that the battery can supply must be measured.

I'd say the *current into a controlled load* must be measured, as that's more commonly what you need batteries for.

Also, you'd want to actually measure at least a partial discharge curve – meaning you count the charge you've drawn from the battery and note down the voltage – in order to know how much capacity is left.

Answer (score 3):

I've spent a career building a few instances of battery-powered equipment, with a lot of planned projects that didn't come to fruition.  This means that I've scrutinized a lot of methods, done a lot of study, but only tried a very few.

So take this with a grain of salt.

For most rechargeable batteries, you can really only tell when a battery is coming close to a full charge or a full discharge.  Anything in between is subject to the condition of the cells, the temperature, the way the cells were manufactured, the ways the manufacturer tweaked the cell chemistry, etc.

This means that **there is no easy way to measure one or two point values and know what's what**.

The current state of the art for laptops & cellphones is "Coulomb counting".  Something in the battery management hardware measures the current going into or out of the battery; something in the battery management software integrates that current into charge (this is the "Coulomb counting" part).  Finally, on better setups, the battery management software resets the state of charge any time the battery comes to full charge, and re-estimates the battery's capacity any time the battery comes to (or close to) a fully discharged state.

If you can't do Coulomb counting, usually the best you can do is charge the cells appropriately and let the user know when the fully discharged state is impending.

For most batteries what you can do is look at the discharge curve and note that there's a "knee" there (sometimes there's a knee but it's only present if you're pulling current -- e.g. dry cells and NiMH).  Further, for most cell chemistries, this knee happens before there's any permanent damage to the cell.  So you can monitor the cell voltage, and if it drops below some magic number you can let the user know that their battery is going to crap out.

If you want to accurately know how much charge is actually left in the battery, though, you need to do Coulomb counting with on-line capacity assessment.